# Laravel Auth Issue

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

I just started to learn Laravel and I was trying to set up an authentication system. I could have used the laravel built in auth but I followed a tutorial to understand the concept. 
My auth system is built using some modals from bootstrap and the system works (kind of).
The sign up works but as soon as I enter the sign in logic the sign up crashes somehow (no errors) and doesn't save my user in the database.

Here's what I'm using:

This is the modal window for the Sign Up. The Log In is pretty much the same, I just changed the action to point to the postSignin method.

```
<!-- Modal Register area -->
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myRegisterLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'UserController@postSignup', 'class' => 'login-form']) !!}
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myRegisterLabel">Sign Up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email:</label>
          {!! Form::text('email', Request::old('email'),['placeholder' => 'Email...']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password:</label>
          {!! Form::password('password', Request::old('password'),['placeholder' => 'Password...']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary login-btn" value="Sign Up">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {!! Form::close() !!}
      @if($errors->any())
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>{{ $error }}</p>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal Register area -->
```

This is how I set up my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignup(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
      ]);

      $user = new User([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
      ]);
      $user->save();

      return redirect('/');
    }

    public function postSignin(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
      ]);

      if (Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
      ])){
        return redirect()->route('user.profile');
      }
      return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function getProfile(){
      return view('user.profile');
    }
}
```

For my routes I used just:

```
Route::post('/','UserController@postSignup');

Route::post('/','UserController@postSignin');
```

So, as I said, as soon as I set up the Log In the Sign up is not registering my user into the DB. If I take it out, it works..
The Log In works either way if I have some users into the DB.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone wondering what was the problem here. It was because of my routes. Both were pointing to '/' which somehow lead to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that both of your routes match. The way routing in Laravel works is that it will go check through your routes sequentially until it finds one which  matches. In this case both situations would match the first route because the URL and the HTTP verb are the same.

A similar, common problem I see encountered is when you have a route with a variable in it.

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostController@show')
Route::get('posts/popular', 'PostController@popular')
```

In this example you would encounter a similar problem because it would match the first route first and wouldn't bother proceeding to the second one.